# Error appearing in QTCreator ("0" error checking failed)

Tags: c++, qt

I am getting the follow error code in QT Creator

```
DTxfrUsb  "0"  error checking failed
```

What I need to know is:

- what does this error mean (syntactically)
- how do i address the problem, or what tips would you suggest to get to the root of this problem?

Thank you

Comment: When do you get this?

Comment: When I run my application, right as it loads and it keeps reappearing

Comment: Is this for an Arduino project?

Comment: yes it is, i compiled an older project onto a new version of QT creator, and I am configuring it to work on a small project of my own.

Comment: Do you have this installed? https://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/

Comment: I am pretty sure i do..

Comment: I just checked and I have that folder saved in my main arduino directory, but perhaps I have not followed proper procedure to install it? How do I know if it is installed?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50732/discussion-between-user2860684-and-jeremy)

Comment: Why would you use QextSerialPort instead of QtSerialPort these day?